# HTML5 checkValidity says an empty input is valid

Tags: javascript, html, checkvalidity

Given the following document:

```
<input pattern="[a-z]"/>
```

Without filling in the input, running:

```
document.querySelector('input').checkValidity()
```

Returns `true`.

Since an empty input would not match `[a-z]`, why is [HTML5 checkValidity()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation) returning `true`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `required` in order to not validate empty input.

```
<input pattern="[a-z]" required />
```

Comment: The rationale behind this design decision is, of course, to be able to validate optional fields.

Comment: You can validate the whole form (which validates all contained inputs) or you can validate fields separately and act accordingly. Both options have advantages/disadvantages

Answer (score 1):

You can get around having to add `required` by adding a check that your value is not empty.  It's pretty obvious, but I thought I would mention it here because I am not posting this input and adding required forces the user to enter a value, which is not what I need.

```
if (myCustomJavaScript.notFalsy($input.val()) && $input[0].checkValidity()) {
 // Submit AJAX request.
}
```